# how to access dataTable variable outside ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have this datatable that is created inside a function call. But if I want to create new rows based on [event listeners like this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html), it gives an error that the table variable is undefined, which is understandable because it is inside a function call and not global. So how do I create a workaround for this and add event listeners under `$(document).ready()` section?

The structure of my JS file is very shabby, but it's intended to be in that way.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     var table=null;
     $('#button').click(function()
     {
         callfunction1();
     }
     callfunction1()
     {
         $.ajax({
              'success': function(response) //response contains the plain table
                         {
                             createDatatable(response)
                         }
         })
     }
     createDatatable(response)
     {
            $('#division').html(response); //creating the plain table
            table=$('#tableId').Datatable({}); //converting it to datatable
     }
     //I want to add event listeners here, because if I add
     //it anywhere else, it doesn't work, because basically
     //it's a function call.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after all your answers(which I am very grateful for) , I have found out a different approach for it. [As per documentation here](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/), I added a `$.ajax({}_.done()` (this is as good as accessing the dataTable variable outside ajax call) function to host my event listener for accessing my dataTable.

Once again, I thank you all for the answers.
Edit: As requested for the correct solution.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     var table=null;
     $('#button').click(function()
     {
         callfunction1();
     }
     callfunction1()
     {
         $.ajax({
              'success': function(response) //response contains the plain table
                         {
                             createDatatable(response)
                         }
         }).done(function()
         {
                 //add event listener here,You can access the table variable here. but you can not access the variable outside, instead just pass the variable to another function.
                 console.log(table);//this will work.
         });
     }
     createDatatable(response)
     {
            $('#division').html(response); //creating the plain table
            table=$('#tableId').Datatable({}); //converting it to datatable
     }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code (an example of the solution) and mark your answer as accepted. Perhaps it will help other people in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a instance of the `table` var in a wider scope, example:

```
//the table is now a window object variable window.table
var table = null;
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $('#button').click(function()
     {
         callfunction1();
     }
     callfunction1()
     {
         $.ajax({
              'success': createDatatable()
         })
     }
     createDatatable()
     {
            table=$('#tableId').Datatable({})
     }

     //the table is binded in the window scope so you can use in your event listeners
}
```

Comment: console.log(table) [which will be null in this case] will be executed before the createDatatable()  function call(AJAX).So this wont work.

Comment: You are right about the `console.log`, i removed the line.

Comment: Well if console.log(table) will be null, then accessing the table inside document.ready() will also return in null, which is what I'm getting.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work if you choose one `var table` declaration and delete the other

```
var table; //accessible everywhere
$(document).ready(function()
{
     var table; //accessible anywhere in this function
     $('#button').click(function() {
         callfunction1();
     }); //); were missing

     function callfunction1 ()
     {
         $.ajax({
              'success': createDatatable //no () here, you want to pass a function, not the result of a function call
         });
     }

     function createDatatable()
     {
            table=$('#tableId').Datatable({});
     }

}
```

This should give no errors, but i'm not sure if this is what you want to do.

Comment: Right now, the table variable inside document.ready is not working and says "undefined" because of ajax call.

Comment: I'm editing the question for a better understanding on the ajax call

Comment: After `var table;`, table is still undefined. It only gets assigned when createDatatable gets called, which only happens on a button click. If you want to create the table immediately, then just put `table=$('#tableId').Datatable({});` at the start of your ready function

Comment: The only problem I see with your edit is that you write `var table` twice. In the createTable function, you have to omit the var and just write `table = ...`

Comment: i've changed to just `table=` but it's still the same

Comment: Where exactly do you determine that table is undefined? I assume that you use console.log(), can you edit your code to show where you do this?

Comment: Last comment in the code the `//I want to add event listener` part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159154/discussion-between-lukilas-and-vishwanth-iron-heart).